# Adding UIGestureRecognizer to view inside UIScrollView

Tags: uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

```
 UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(textTapped:)];
    tap.delegate = self;
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;

    for(PaginationView* page in self.flashView._innerScrollView.subviews) {
        [page addGestureRecognizer:tap];
    }
```

I have a custom view called a PaginationView and I have several of them in a UIScrollView.

I'd like to add a gesture recognizer for each of them. 
It appears to add the gesture recognizer to the PaginationViews fine, but the "textTapped" method is never called.

My delegate implements this method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    return YES;
}
```

And this is set in my PaginationView init method:

```
self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Thanks!